# Outlook 2010 crashing when opening any file dialog

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

Outlook 2010 freezes whenever I open any file dialog (e.g. opening an outlook file, browsing to attach a file, browsing to a hyperlink). This is before the dialog has even appeared, so isn't to do with file size.

I can still browse between any Outlook windows I have open, but all of them are individually frozen.

When I use Task Manager to crash out of it, I can see the file dialog sitting behind everything else for a split second before it dissapears - most of it is greyed out.

Has anyone suffered a similar problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by going to File > Account Settings > Account Settings > Repair.